# Rename within in for loop in windows

Tags: r, for-loop, rename, file-rename

Rename function is not working ,I have tried the following

```
for (i in 1:length(file_list))
    {
         dest=paste("D:/R/Hr/New1",file_list[i],sep="/")
         exe <- "C:\\Program Files\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe"
         system(paste("\"", exe, "\" \"", dest, "\"", sep = ""), wait = F)
         filetxt <- sub(".pdf", ".txt", dest)
         fdest=paste("D:/R/Hr/New2/",file_list[i],sep="")
         fdest <- sub(".pdf", ".txt",fdest)
         #my.file.rename(filetxt,fdest)
         file.rename(filetxt,fdest)
    }
```

but not a single file renamed though without loop its working fine

```
        i=1
> dest=paste("D:/R/Hr/New1",file_list[i],sep="/")
>          exe <- "C:\\Program Files\\xpdfbin-win-3.03\\bin32\\pdftotext.exe"
>          system(paste("\"", exe, "\" \"", dest, "\"", sep = ""), wait = F)
>          filetxt <- sub(".pdf", ".txt", dest)
>          fdest=paste("D:/R/Hr/New2/",file_list[i],sep="")
>          fdest <- sub(".pdf", ".txt",fdest)
>          #my.file.rename(filetxt,fdest)
>          file.rename(filetxt,fdest)
[1] TRUE
```

Just didnt unerstand why this problem and how can I get rid of this,and same o/p with this function also

```
my.file.rename <- function(from, to) {
  todir <- dirname(to)
  if (!isTRUE(file.info(todir)$isdir)) dir.create(todir, recursive=TRUE)
  file.rename(from = from,  to = to)
}
```

why am i not getting expected renamed within in for loop,any help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for any loops and it seems to work fine on a Mac:

```
file_list = list.files("~/test/",pattern="*.pdf",full.names=TRUE)
fdest= sub(".pdf", ".txt",file_list)
file.rename(file_list,fdest)
print(list.files("~/test/",pattern="*.pdf",full.names=TRUE))
print(list.files("~/test/",pattern="*.txt",full.names=TRUE))
```

My guess is your `wait = F` in the system call allows the code to continue before your executable has produced a file (and even if it did, it could be locked). Try setting it to true and running this code after you have done all your calls to pdftotext.exe